# Error installing iKernel.exe

Tags: windows-server-2003

Has anybody come across this problem during an application install?

- OS is Windows Server 2k3

I do have local Admin access and I have installed this application on other machines.
Any help would be much appreciated, as Google isn't helping much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may occur if one or more of the following files are missing from the Windows\System32 folder:

- Stdole32.tlb
- Stdole2.tlb
- Stdole.tlb

To resolve this issue, expand the appropriate file from the Windows Server 2003 Installation disk:

(using the command prompt)

```
Expand cd_drive_letter:\i386\filename.tl_ drive:\Windows\system32\filename.tlb
```

and then press **ENTER**.

- **filename** is the name of the file that you want to expand
- **drive** is the letter of the drive where Windows is installed